# Creating a formula / macro to compare two sets of data and if they match to change the colour of a cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to work out a formula or macro to automate a task that is laborious.

I have to compare two sets of data and if they match I change the colour of a cell to show the task has been completed by a crew member.

As the crew size increases this is causing the task to become more time consuming.

The task is required to done twice a week (Monday & Thursday) by crew members.

We receive data from an external company and then if the task is done, I update our spreadsheet showing this on the crew members row and corresponding cell for that date.

I presume I will need to do an IF statement to show if the statement is true change the colour of the cell.

Hope that makes sense?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule with `match()`.